# How to capture JNDI JDBC connection in Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

We have a JEE web application running on Wildfly web server which is using JNDI lookup for Oracle database connection. I am able to see all the metrics for logs, http tracing, however I am not able see JNDI JDBC calls in Application map view or in Search view.

[image]

Microsoft doc :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-agent

Code :

```
Connection conn=null;
        try{            
            //get JNDI JDBC connection
            Context context = (Context)new InitialContext();
            DataSource ods = (DataSource)context.lookup(MyPropertieFileReader.getInstance().getProperty(Constants.JDNI_NAME));      
            conn = ods.getConnection();                 
        }
```

My intention is I want to monitory JDBC dependency calls in Azure Application insights. Could you please guide is there any way that I can monitory JNDI JDBC calls ?

Comment: What is your hosting service. Like "Azure App Service" or?

Comment: @KrishnenduGhosh-MSFT No, our war is deployed in Wildfly web server which is hosted in Azure Virtual machine.

Comment: Ok. I would like to know about your app platform ..supported for `standalone` like yours  are listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-standalone-arguments . Also note that standalone environment is in public preview at this moment  https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/codeless-overview . Also I hope you have seen this? https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/app/java-in-process-agent

Comment: Yes, I am using JBoss EAP 7
Standalone server.  Thanks for the information. Now my question is what is the impact if I go standalone agent  configuration with public preview to production environment ?

Comment: Should be fine as long as you keep an eye to update when GA release happens..